# Java DatagramSocket - can't recived two packets at the same time

Tags: java

So I'm programming 2D MMO game and I'm stuck. My client can't receive two packets at the same time and I don't know why. So first piece of code was very simple - I send ping packet to server and then Server send me packet with information about level - every second and it worked. But now i want to make it easier. I want to recive packet at the begining of the game(after login in to the game) and then after movement. But it doesn't work. Here is my piece of code from Client Network Thread:

```
public void run()
{
    while(clientRunning)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte [1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

        //SendPingPacket.SendPing(c_socket, c_ipAdress, c_port);

        try
        {
            c_socket.receive(packet);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PacketHandler.HandlePacket(data, c_socket, packet.getAddress(),
                packet.getPort());
    }
}
```

And Client's JPanel:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            MoveSender.SendMoveData(m_playerID, 0, m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
            AskForLevelSender.SendAskForLevel(GameBoard.m_playerID,
                    m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            MoveSender.SendMoveData(m_playerID, 1, m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
            AskForLevelSender.SendAskForLevel(GameBoard.m_playerID,
                    m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            MoveSender.SendMoveData(m_playerID, 3, m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
            AskForLevelSender.SendAskForLevel(GameBoard.m_playerID,
                    m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
        }
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            MoveSender.SendMoveData(m_playerID, 2, m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
            AskForLevelSender.SendAskForLevel(GameBoard.m_playerID,
                    m_socket.GetSocket(), m_ipAddress, m_port);
        }
    }
```

Please help with this problem :)

Comment: UDP packets aren't like TCP, they aren't completely reliable and you can't be sure that they have reached their destination so the 'update when changed' method doesn't really work. The other method works because even if one message was lost the messages coming in after would make up for it.

Comment: Okey, I've changed UDP Protocol to TCP and everthing is fine :)
Thanks for your help :)